# How to get sdk/panel name or id from httpChannel (nsIHttpChannel) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, httprequest, firefox-addon-sdk

Does anyone know how to get panel (sdk/panel) name, id or any other tags from Firefox `httpChannel` request (`nsIHttpChannel`)?

I need to identify the panel (for my extension) and listen to specific requests (http Request Observer) only from my panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get access to the raw xul node, you migfht be able to use the modelFor / viewFor utilities in the sdk - this works for tabs at least. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Converting_to_XUL_tabs) for more info, here is an example:

```
var { modelFor } = require("sdk/model/core");
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");

var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var tab_utils = require("sdk/tabs/utils");

function mapHighLevelToLowLevel(tab) {
  // get the XUL tab that corresponds to this high-level tab
  var lowLevelTab = viewFor(tab);
  // now we can, for example, access the tab's content directly
  var browser = tab_utils.getBrowserForTab(lowLevelTab);
  console.log(browser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
  // get the high-level tab back from the XUL tab
  var highLevelTab = modelFor(lowLevelTab);
  console.log(highLevelTab.url);
}

tabs.on("ready", mapHighLevelToLowLevel);
```